# Sql need help for update query

Tags: sql

I need help. I have the table wich contains 1 or 2 row for each user. look like

```
| UserId | CreateOn   | order | 
|-----------------------------|
| 1      | 2014-01-01 | NULL  | 
|--------|------------|-------|
| 1      | 2014-01-02 | NULL  | 
|--------|------------|-------|
| 2      | 2014-02-01 | NULL  |
|--------|------------|-------|
| 2      | 2014-02-02 | NULL  |
|--------|------------|-------|
| 3      | 2014-03-01 | NULL  |
```

I need to set order in 1 or 2 dependency by createOn for each userId

Edit: I use Ms Sql Server
I try something like this

```
UPDATE table1
SET Order = 1
WHERE UserId = 1 AND CreatedOn > (
                SELECT TOP 1 t2.CreatedOn 
                FROM table2 t2
                WHERE t2.UserId = 1
                ORDER BY t2.CreatedOn DESC)
```

but it works only for 1 row

Edit2: Result must look like

```
| UserId | CreateOn   | order | 
|-----------------------------|
| 1      | 2014-01-01 | 1  | 
|--------|------------|-------|
| 1      | 2014-01-02 | 2  | 
|--------|------------|-------|
| 2      | 2014-02-01 | 1  |
|--------|------------|-------|
| 2      | 2014-02-02 | 2  |
|--------|------------|-------|
| 3      | 2014-03-01 | 1  |
```

Comment: Can you make you question a little clearer please? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: What are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL.. etc?

Comment: Oracle, MySql, PostgreSQL, SQLServer... ? have you tried "something" ?

Comment: Try google "sql row number" + your dbms name (mssql,mysql,oracle...)

Comment: I would suggest posting an example of the expected result. This will make the question a lot clearer

Comment: Describe problem understandable and with some codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I undertsand you correctly, here is how you would do it in SQL Server, using windowing (the over() clause) and a common table expression:

```
create table #test(userid int,CreateOn date,[order] int);

insert into #test(userid,CreateOn) VALUES
    (1,'2014-01-01'),
    (1,'2014-01-02'),
    (2,'2014-02-01'),
    (2,'2014-02-02'),
    (3,'2014-03-01');

with testCTE as (   
    select userid,CreateOn,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by userid order by createon) as NewOrder
    from #test
)
update t
set [order] = tc.NewOrder
from #test t 
join testCTE tc on tc.userid = t.userid
    and tc.CreateOn = t.CreateOn

select * from #test
```

This will give results that look like this:

```
userid      CreateOn   order
1           2014-01-01 1
1           2014-01-02 2
2           2014-02-01 1
2           2014-02-02 2
3           2014-03-01 1
```

Comment: Also, you didn't specify what version of SQL Server you are using.  This may not work in 2000.

Comment: Good to hear.  If you're not sure on some of this, I'd suggest looking up CTE's (Common Table Expressions) and windowing.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle version:

```
merge into the_table
using
(
    select rowid as rid,
           row_number() over (partition by userid order by createon) as rn
    from the_table
) t on (t.rid = the_table.rowid) 
when matched then 
   set "order" = rn;
```

Postgres version:

```
with numbered as (
  select ctid as cid,
         row_number() over (partition by userid order by createon) as rn
  from the_table
)
update the_table
  set "order" = rn
from numbered
where numbered.cid = the_table.ctid;
```